# Writting list of list in CSV while all value of a list in Single cell

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a list made up of multiple list to export in csv

```
export_list = [['abc'],['1','2','3','4','5'],['m','n','o']]
```

I tried to export the list using csv

```
outfile = open("./out.csv","wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerows(export_list)
```

But the ouput came with each element seperated shown below:

```
 abc  |   |  |   |    |   
    1 |2  |3 | 4 | 5  |   
    m |n  |o |   |    |
```

But I want to format it to be stored like this

```
list1 |     list2            |  list3           |
  abc |   1 2 3 4 5          |   m n o          |
```

What's the correct way of achieving this?
Note: I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was trying to insert  all values of a list in respective column.

The first answer was working but it populates the data in row. So below code helped me out

```
cars = ['audi','bugati', 'mustang']
car_cell = ' '.join(cars)
bikes = ['bmw','ktm','ninja']
bike_cell = ' '.join(bikes)

with open('./output.csv', "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['List1','List2'])
    writer.writerow([car_cell, bike_cell])
```

This would literate the table in my expected format.
The `join` helped to join all the elements of a list to a single element and `writerow` to write one list per column.

Answer (score 0):

Add the delimiter keyword

```
outfile = open("./out.csv","wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')
writer.writerows(export_list)
```

Also, upgrade to python 3

This exact code worked for me

```
import csv
export_list = [['abc'],['1','2','3','4','5'],['m','n','o']]
with open('test.csv','w',newline='') as cfile:
    cwrite=csv.writer(cfile,delimiter=',')
    cwrite.writerows(export_list)
```

`test.csv` turns out like this

```
abc
1,2,3,4,5
m,n,o
```

Comment: Still the output is seperated. Didn't Worked

Comment: Hm, try changing `wb` to just `w`

Comment: i edited with the exact code that just worked for me, if that doesn't work for you, something fishy is going on

Comment: it gave _'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function_

Answer (score 0):

`csv` is treating each element in the sublist as its own column; to avoid that, join the elements with a `' '`:

```
import csv
export_list = [['abc'],['1','2','3','4','5'],['m','n','o']]
with open('filename.csv', 'w') as f:
   write = csv.writer(f)
   write.writerows([[' '.join(i) for i in export_list]])
```

Comment: The result was set vertically. I need the list to be placed horizontally. Also there was gap between each cell